# std::packaged_task not breaking promises on destruction?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, future, packaged-task

I'm encountering something very weird when using packaged tasks. When reading [~packaged_task](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/~packaged_task) I get the impression that if a `std::packaged_task` is destroyed before it is executed, the promise will be broken and an attempt to get the result from the future should throw `std::future_error`.

However, on Visual Studio 2013 this doesn't seem to be the case. Take this following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::future<int> f;
    {
        std::packaged_task<int()> task([](){return 3; });
        f = task.get_future();
    }
    std::cout<<f.get()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting to get an `std::future_error` on `f.get()` but instead it blocks, waiting for the packaged task to be executed.

Trying another compiler: http://ideone.com/Wt0WOc does indeed throw a `std::future_error("Broken promise")`...

Am I seeing a bug in Visual Studio 2013 or have I missed something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct. `~packaged_task()` abandons the shared state (§30.6.9.1 [futures.task.members]/p9), which means, if the shared state is not ready, storing an exception object of type `future_error` with error condition of `broken_promise`, then making the shared state ready; and then releasing the shared state (§30.6.4 [futures.state]/p7).

This is a [known bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809632/destroying-a-packaged-task-does-not-abandon-the-shared-state) that [will be fixed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/06/c-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx) in the next version of Visual Studio, which is likely to come out some time in 2015. It's also fixed in the CTP, but it's a pretty bad idea to use that for production code...

Comment: So did I read those links correctly, this will not be fixed in VS 2013?

Comment: @EmilyL. I'd say very unlikely. According to [Q5 in the FAQ section of this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx), they backport bugfixes only rarely.

Comment: Great, the studio we bought is barely a year old and they are already leaving us in a pinch. *sigh* Thanks for the confirmation. Accepting this answer as the links put the final confirmation on my suspicions.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's a bug, the standard says `~packaged_task` abandons the shared state, which means that if it isn't ready yet it should store a `broken_promise` exception and make the state ready, just as you expect.

Full disclosure: your ideone.com test uses GCC and I implemented GCC's `<future>` so I might be biased when I say its behaviour is correct ... but I think it is still correct ;-)

Comment: Fully agreed. An abandoned `future` (i.e. the return value in this case) is *the* situation for a `broken_promise`.